# Recommended way to embed Google Drive inside a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, webview, google-drive-api

I have embedded a Google Drive webpage inside a webView in Mac OS X, but in this case the webpage is not fully functional:

1. It's not possible to Drag & Drop a file from the filesystem inside a document, (while it's possible to drop an image from another application)
2. The "Share" button does not work
3. The Print Button does not work
4. Multiple entries for the same user appear into the chat when opening the same document various times. The expected behavior is that the number of entries decrease when the user close the page. [image: The chat with multiple entries for the same user] When a document is shown inside a Mac OS X WebView, the number of entries is increased correctly when opening a page, but it do not decrease when the WebView is closed.

I want to understand what is the recommended way to embed a Google Drive page inside a WebView to avoid all these issues.

---

Additionals information:

1. [WebView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. All the requests are authenticated using the Google Drive Oauth access token.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current recommended way of doing this, it should just work as if you are viewing Google Drive in any browser. Authorization should be done by the cookie though, Oauth token won't help you here.